# Scala object mapper exception while creating delta sharing rest client in Java

Tags: java, delta-lake, rest-client, delta-sharing

I am trying to create a delta sharing rest client which is accessing shares located in azure blob storage. It's throwing this exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/ScalaObjectMapper

Below is my client code
`

```
String profileFile = "./profile.share";
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.Impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb");
config.set("fs.azure.block.blob.with.compaction.dir", "/hbase/WALs,/data/myblobfiles");
config.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
config.set("fs.azure.enable.append.support", "true");
DeltaSharingProfileProvider profileProvider = new DeltaSharingFileProfileProvider(config, profileFile);
DeltaSharingClient restClient = new DeltaSharingRestClient(profileProvider, 40, 5, true, false);
restClient.listAllTables();
```

`

I have placed my account name and account key in the config as well (removed here). Have added all these dependencies in my gradle build

```
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
implementation"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.1.RELEASE"
implementation"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.3.1.RELEASE"
implementation"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.1.RELEASE"
implementation"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.1.RELEASE"
implementation("io.delta:delta-standalone_2.12:0.6.0")
implementation("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.3.1")
implementation("org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:1.10.1")
implementation("io.delta:delta-sharing-spark_2.12:0.6.0")
implementation 'io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0'
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: it looks like a problem with gradle - it looks like you aren't creating a fat jar